# Methods in Ruby: objects or not?

Tags: ruby, object, methods, language-features

Inspired by [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599161/class-method-as-hash-value/2599661#2599661), after some googling I wasn't able to find an answer to a pretty simple question regarding methods in Ruby: are methods objects or not?

There are different opinions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416047/examples-of-things-that-are-not-objects-in-ruby/416154#416154) and [there](http://www.mentby.com/david-a-black/are-methods-objects.html), and I would really like to hear, let's say, an in-depth explanation.

I'm aware of `Object#method` method, which takes a method name and returns a `Method` instance, but, on the other hand, there's a similar thing you can do with blocks to make them into `Proc` instances, and blocks aren't objects, so what makes methods any different?

Comment: Functions are first-class citizens in Ruby and can be converted to objects, so why worry? I think answer will lay too low level to make much sense...

Comment: Are they? IMHO, the fact that you need to convert them to objects makes them not-first-class. That's what I'd want to learn from the answers as well.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

> Methods are a fundamental part of
>   Ruby's syntax, but they are not values
>   that Ruby programs can operate on.
>   That is, **Ruby's methods are not
>   objects** in the way that strings,
>   numbers, and arrays are. It is
>   possible, however, to obtain a Method
>   object that represents a given method,
>   and we can invoke methods indirectly
>   through Method objects.

From [The Ruby Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516177):
[image]

Comment: Hi,

If  methods are not object then how it possible?

    `irb(main):015:0> def hi
    irb(main):016:1> "hello"
    irb(main):017:1> end
    => nil
    irb(main):018:0> hi.object_id
    => 22452528
    irb(main):019:0> hi.object_id.send hi
    => "hi"
    irb(main):020:0> hi.object_id.send(hi)
    => "hi"`

Comment: `hi.object_id` first calls method `hi`, and then returns the object_id of its result (which is string `"hello"`).

Answer (score 23):

You can't really tell.

The only way to get access to a method is to send the `#method` message to some object, which will then return a `Method` object. But is that `Method` object the method itself? Or is it a wrapper around the method? Or is it a converted version of the original method?

You can't know: if you want to look at a method, you have to call `#method`, at which point you definitely *will* get an object. What it was *before* you called `#method` you can't look at, therefore you can't tell.

A couple of datapoints: in Ruby, everything returns a value. What does `def` return? It *always* returns `nil`, not a `Method` object. And `define_method`? It returns a `Proc`, but not a `Method` (nor an `UnboundMethod`). [Note: in Rubinius, `def` returns the compiled bytecode of the method, but still not a `Method` object.]

If you look at the 4th and 5th paragraphs of Section 6.1 of the Ruby Language Specification (lines 29-34 and 1-5 on pages 5 and 6), you can clearly see that there is a distinction drawn between methods and objects. And if you look at the specification of the builtin classes, you will find that neither `Method` nor `UnboundMethod` are in there, nor is `Object#method`. IOW: you can build a perfectly standards-compliant Ruby interpreter in which methods *aren't* objects.

Now, blocks OTOH definitely *aren't* objects. There are many ways to *construct* `Proc` objects from blocks, which then have the same behavior as the original block (`lambda`, `proc`, `Proc.new`, the `&` sigil), but blocks themselves aren't objects.

Think about it this way: you can pass a string to `File.new` to construct a file object, but that doesn't make a string a file. You can pass a block to `Proc.new` to construct a proc object, but that doesn't make a block a proc.

Comment: Just for the reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294485/how-do-i-reference-a-function-in-ruby/4294660#4294660

Comment: Not wanting to sound sarcastic, but what is a block? Is it merely a piece of text in a .rb file?

Comment: Jörg clarified that Ruby methods are not objects in a later StackOverflow question @MladenJablanović links to.  Here's the quote: "Note, however, that both the Method and the UnboundMethod are wrappers around the method, not the method itself. Methods are not objects in Ruby. (Contrary to what I have written in other answers, BTW. I really need to go back and fix those.)"

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Blocks are blocks. They are a distinct entity that can only be acted on in certain ways.

Answer (score 11):

In Ruby, methods and blocks are not, in and of themselves, native or first-class objects. However, they can very easily be wrapped in objects, such that it generally makes no difference.

But try out, and keep in mind the result of,

```
a = Object.method(:new).object_id
b = Object.method(:new).object_id
a == b
=> false
```

In Haskell, all values (including numbers as well as lambdas and functions) are first-class values. In every aspect of the language, they are all treated equivalently. This is not the case in Ruby, but it can be approximated.

Comment: Justice, your argument was the same as mine. In addition, I'm not aware of any other way to return methods, so #method(method_name) seems to be the only way to reference a method at all, aside from calling it by name on it's original object.

Comment: The only thing that your object_id proves is that they are not immediates. `a = 1.0.object_id; b = 1.0.object_id; a == b  # => false`

Answer (score 2):

Objects and Methods are not the same even if the return value for the methods is an object and not nil.
Objects live on the heap unless in a method, lambda, or proc scope and the method itself lives on the stack and has an address assign after interpretation while static and class objects are allocated on the heap. Ruby still uses C to interpret it and pass it to the VALUE struct.

Comment: From ruby's perspective Methods are Objects. The implementation details are not important. A method can be addresses and passed just like any other object. Procs are also Objects (and blocks are just a syntactic way of creating a Proc/lambda).

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, methods are not objects.  This is confusing because there is a Method class and you can get instances of Method.  These instances are just proxies for the method itself.  These instances provide some useful functionality. They have some internal magic that hooks them up to the actual method (so you can do things like `Method#call`) but you can't actually access that stuff (AFAIK).

```
1.method(:to_s).object_id == 1.method(:to_s).object_id #=> false
```

This means either that `1` has two `#to_s` methods (which it does not) or that what is returned by the method `#method` is not actually the method itself but some proxy for the method.  If methods were actually objects then you would have situations where you were able to get the same instance twice. If methods were objects then you would be able to do things like set an instance variable on them and them, later, get the value of that instance variable after a second retrieval of the method object.  You can't do that.  So, while it may *generally* make no difference, there are situations where I find I am unable to do things that I would like to.

```
1.method(:to_s).instance_variable_set(:@foo, 'foo') #=> "foo" 
1.method(:to_s).instance_variable_get(:@foo)        #=> nil 
# And just in case you question it...
1.object_id == 1.object_id                          #=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Because parenthesis are optional in ruby, method objects are generally "hidden" in the sense you need to explicitly fetch the method object via the `method` method. However if you make the effort to capture a method object it becomes quite clear that it acts like an object. Since Ruby >= 2.1 this is easier to take advantage of than ever.

For example, you can get your methods to behave more like they do in Javascript (where no parens is the method object and parens are used to call the method) like so:

```
foo = method def foo
  def a(num)
    3 * num.to_i
  end

  n = yield if block_given?
  a(n || 3)
rescue
  "oops!"
end

def foo.bar(num)
  a(num)
end

foo.class #=> Method
foo() #=> 9
foo.call #=> 9
foo.call{2} #=> 6
foo(){2} #=> 6
foo.call{ raise "blam!" } #=> "oops!"
foo.bar(5) #=> 15
```

[See this gist](https://gist.github.com/burlesona/5426c1f3a4b9b235f22b) for a version with these example written as tests.

[JRL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2602485/417872) quotes Matz book saying that methods are not objects *like strings etc.* are, but method objects are real, and other than the parens/no-parens thing they act pretty much like any other ruby object. It's a [duck-typed language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), so I'd say that qualifies methods as objects in my book.