# Is ruby really an fully object oriented language?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ruby is **fully object oriented language**.  In ruby, everything is an object & therefore, belongs to some class. for example `5` belongs to `Object class`

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > 5.class
 => Fixnum 
1.9.3p194 :002 > 5.class.superclass
 => Integer 
1.9.3p194 :003 > 5.class.superclass.superclass
 => Numeric 
1.9.3p194 :005 > 5.class.superclass.superclass.superclass
 => Object 
1.9.3p194 :006 > 5.class.superclass.superclass.superclass.superclass
 => BasicObject 
1.9.3p194 :007 > 5.class.superclass.superclass.superclass.superclass.superclass
 => nil
```

so, we have to call all methods by prefixing class/object name as in `Object_name#method_name`. example:

```
5.times{|i| puts i}
```

now, rails has these so called helpers like `stylesheet_link_tag`, `javascript_include_tag`, `form_for` etc which do follow this `Object_name#method_name` syntax, so i guess they are just normal functions.

so my question is

1. What are these rails helpers?
2. If they just functions & do not
   inherit from any class. Doesn't that contradict the claim made
   saying - in ruby, `everything a object & there are no primitives`.
   As the example, people cite `5.+(6)` saying even operators are just
   plain methods?

Comment: When you see method invocation without explicit receiver, then the receiver is `self`. How exactly did you conclude that "everything is an object" isn't true?

Comment: Ohk,I didn't know about `self`. I guess I was wrong, thanks!

Comment: I'll upgrade this to an answer :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is Ruby fully Object Oriented?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106430/how-is-ruby-fully-object-oriented)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [ActionView::Helpers](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/)
- [ActionController::Helpers](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Helpers)

For other things called without a receiver, look at the `Kernel` module, where stuff like `puts` is defined. Since the module is included in `Object`, its methods are available everywhere. How exactly would that contradict the -- IMHO overused -- claim that everything is an object?

Comment: So these methods are defined in a module, instead of class? your answer has become my *aha* moment of the day. interesting!

Answer (score 5):

These rails assets tag helpers are a sub module of ActionView, `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper` which provides methods for generating HTML that links views to assets such as images, javascripts, stylesheets, and feed.

As `modules` have `class` as a superclass it mean that the AssetTagHelpers will also have it

```
irb(main):016:0> ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
=> ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
irb(main):017:0> ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper.class
=> Module
irb(main):018:0> ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper.class.superclass
=> Object
irb(main):019:0> ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper.class.superclass.superclass
=> BasicObject
irb(main):020:0> ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper.class.superclass.superclass.superclass
=> nil
```

NOTE: For sake of simplicity I will only focus on the JavascriptIncludeTag but they are all pretty similar.

Here you will find a class called `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper::JavascriptIncludeTag`

Which you can be instantiate

```
JavascriptIncludeTag.new(config, asset_paths)
```

The JavascriptIncludeTag class has a method called `asset_tag` which then calls a `content_tag` method and returns the correct tag.

path: /actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helpers/javascript_tag_helpers.rb

```
require 'action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helpers/asset_include_tag'

# NOTE: on the 'action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helpers/asset_include_tag' it requires '/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb' so now all this files are connected :)
.
.
.
def asset_tag(source, options)
  content_tag("script", "", { "src" => path_to_asset(source) }.merge(options))
end
```

path: /actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb

```
def content_tag(name, content_or_options_with_block = nil, options = nil, escape = true, &block)
  if block_given?
    options = content_or_options_with_block if content_or_options_with_block.is_a?(Hash)
    content_tag_string(name, capture(&block), options, escape)
  else
    content_tag_string(name, content_or_options_with_block, options, escape)
  end
end
```

So that is more less how they work.

NOTE: If you found my explanation a bit tricky just let me know and I'll edited to provide a better explanation

Answer (score 4):

When you see method invocation without explicit receiver, then the receiver is `self`. Objects can get methods in many different ways. One, most obvious, is when you define methods yourself. Then you can also include modules.

```
class Person
  # this adds a bunch of methods to Person, making it a Mongoid model
  include Mongoid::Document
end
```

Modules you include and classes you inherit from can acquire functionality in the same manner.

So, when you see method without receiver, think "what is `self` at this point? What is its class? What methods has it defined? What modules does it include?" You'll discover many interesting things about ruby and rails. :)