# How does Ruby's .() operator work?

Tags: ruby, methods, syntax, service-object

I recently came across [some code](http://sporto.github.io/blog/2012/11/15/a-pattern-for-service-objects-in-rails/) using a method call consisting of the format `object.(arg1, arg2)`  without seeing a good explanation of how it works. See this sample code:

```
class TestServiceObject
  def call
    'method'
  end
end

TestServiceObject.new.()
# => 'method'
```

What's the term for this kind of shorthand?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4294660/646668) looks like what you're looking for. For future reference, [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/) is quite handy for looking up language syntax...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The dot-parentheses notation is a shorthand way for passing arguments to the implicit [`call`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Method.html#method-i-call) method on a Ruby object:

```
foo = lambda {|bar| puts bar}

foo.call('baz')
#=> baz
foo.('baz')

foo.call('baz') === foo.('baz')
#=> true
```

Also note that the following notations are also valid (and equivalent) invocations of the `call` method:

```
foo['baz']
#=> baz
foo::('baz')
#=> baz
```

In your example, you're *explicitly overriding* the `call` method on the `TestServiceObject` class such that it returns the string `'method'` when called. Accordingly, you can explicitly override the the `call` method to accept arguments:

```
class TestServiceObject
  def call(foo=nil)
    foo || 'method'
  end
end

TestServiceObject.new.()
#=> method
TestServicesObject.new.('bar')
#=> bar
```

**UPDATE**:

As commenter [@LoganSerman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29595/logan-serman) duly notes, the shorthand operator appears to work on anything that responds to `call`, which is validated in part by the following example:

```
m = 12.method("+")

m.call(3)
#=> 15
m.(3)
#=> 15
```

**UPDATE 2**:

As commenter [@Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477037/stefan) also points out from [the documentation on `Proc#call`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Proc.html#method-i-call):

> prc.() invokes prc.call() with the parameters given. It’s a syntax sugar to hide “call”.

Comment: From [`Proc#call`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Proc.html#method-i-call): *"Note that prc.() invokes prc.call() with the parameters given. It’s a syntax sugar to hide “call”."*

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you can also invoke `call` with square brackets `m[3]` and with the scope resolution operator `m::(3)`

Comment: Very right. I've amended my answer for the sake of completeness.

Comment: "The dot-parentheses notation is a shorthand way for passing arguments to the implicit `call` method on a Ruby object" – This is wrong. There is no such thing as an "implicit `call` method". Ruby doesn't *have* implicit methods. You may be thinking of Scala, which is (to my knowledge) the only language which has implicits.

Comment: "Also note that the following notations are also valid (and equivalent) invocations of the `call` method: `foo['baz']`" – This is wrong: the indexing operator translates into a call to the `[]` method, not to the `call` method. `foo['baz']` is equivalent to `foo.[]('baz')`, not `foo.call('baz')`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag isn't `a_proc.call(arg)` equivalent to `a_proc[arg]`?

Comment: `a_proc[arg]` is translated to `a_proc.[](arg)` and *not* to `a_proc.call(arg)`. The translation for the `[]` indexing operator doesn't magically change depending on the object, it is *always* translated into a call to the `[]` method and *never* to the `call` method, regardless of whether the object is an `Array`, a `Hash`, a `Proc` or a `FooBarFrobnicatorThingamajingy`.

Comment: That's right, but for `Proc` and `Method`, `#[]` and `#call` are equivalent.

Comment: They are "equivalent" only in that there is a `[]` method which has the same implementation as the `call` method. That's it.

Answer (score 6):

```
foo.(bar, baz)
```

is interpreted as

```
foo.call(bar, baz)
```

just like

```
foo + bar
```

is interpreted as

```
foo.+(bar)
```

or

```
foo[bar, baz] = quux
```

is interpreted as

```
foo.[]=(bar, baz, quux)
```

The intention is to make calling function-like objects look similar to calling methods:

```
foo.(bar, baz) # function
foo(bar, baz)  # method
```

Despite claims in other answers to this question, it has nothing to do with an "implicit `call` method" (Ruby doesn't even *have* implicit methods, only Scala does) or the indexing operator.

The indexing operator is translated into a different method call (`[]`) and *not* into a call to `call`:

```
o = Object.new

def o.call(*args); "`call` called with #{args.join(', ')}" end

o.(42)
# => "`call` called with 42"

o[42]
# NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<Object:0xdeadbeefc0ffee>

def o.[](*args);   "`[]` called with #{args.join(', ')}"   end

o[42]
# => "`[]` called with 42"
```

Comment: ruby... what a mess  :)

Answer (score 5):

`obj.(args)` is just a feature provided through the parser. Not technically an alias, but it simply has the same effect as invoking `obj.call(args)` on an object that defines the `call` method.