# Ruby on Rails - Is params a method or a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I am trying out the **Getting Started** section of the Ruby on Rails guides [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

I did not understand a [line](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-articles) in this tutorial. Quoting it:

> The **params method** is the object which represents the parameters (or fields) coming in from the form.

I do have some previous experience in rails, and I always assumed `params` is a hash. But here they call it a `method which is an object`.

Is `params` a `method` or a `hash`? Also, in ruby, are methods also objects?

Comment: It's bad wording. It should say *"The params method **returns** an object which represents..."*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The description is a little bit truncated. To be precise, it should be read as:

   > The return value of the `params` method is [an] object ...

   A method is not an object, but when you execute a method, it always returns an object. In this case, `params` is a method, not an object, but has a return value, which is an object.
2. In older versions of Rails, the return value of `params` used to be a hash, but now, it isn't a hash.

Comment: @EricDuminil Hey, don't try to confuse beginners. An instance of `Method` class is created by a method named `method`, and is an object. It is distinct from a method.

Comment: You're right. I've read more about it in an answer by our [Ruby god](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4294660/6419007), and deleted my previous comment.

Comment: Eric's previous comment made me run `puts method(:params).source_location`. It led me to https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4b969ea417f097d217ff1f662d2fe8c406d21b99/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb where I literally saw the `params` method ;)

Answer (score 16):

- `params` is a **method** that returns an `ActionController::Parameters` **object**. Think of it something like this:

  ```
  def params
    ActionController::Parameters.new(...)
  end
  ```

  **Example (somewhere in your controller or view)**:

  ```
  puts params
  #=> <ActionController::Parameters ...>
  puts params.is_a? Object
  #=> true
  ```
- A **method** in Ruby always return a **value** (note: `nil` is also a **value**) unless that **method** is not defined. Keep in mind though that `params` is already defined by Rails even if you do not see it in your code)
- Every "returned value" of a **method** in Ruby is an **object**. Even `nil` value is a `NilClass` **object**. Integers, Strings, Arrays, and Hashes are also **objects**. Why? Because eveeeeery thing inherits/starts of from the `Object` **class**.
- **If < Rails 5.1:**

  - `ActionController::Parameters` inherits from `Hash` **class**, which means that you can use all `Hash` **methods** ([see Hash methods here](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash)).

    **Example:**

    ```
    params.sort ...
    params.each ...
    params.has_key?(:controller)
    ```
- **But now at >= Rails 5.1:**

  - `ActionController::Parameters` **NO LONGER** inherits from `Hash` **class**, so you would think that you can no longer use methods such as the above code like `.sort`, or `.has_key?`, but you still can! because `ActionController::Parameters` defines its own custom methods that "look like" methods from a `Hash`.

    - **NOTE:** Not all Hash methods are redefined in `ActionController::Parameters`. Feel free to compare the methods [HERE](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) and [HERE](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash), in particular `sort` method which is `Hash` method was not redefined in `ActionController::Parameters`, so you can't do `params.sort` anymore in Rails >= 5.1.

Answer (score 3):

`params` is a method which returns an object - instance of [`ActionController::Parameters`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html).

It has methods that make it behave much like a hash, but it is a bit more complex than a hash.

> Also, in Ruby, are methods also objects?

[Check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602340/methods-in-ruby-objects-or-not).

Comment: then why do they call it **params method**?

Comment: @mridula I rephrased the answer

Comment: `method which returns an object` might give the impression that some methods don't return any object.

Comment: @EricDuminil I don't read it this way. To me it just answers straightforwardly the question whether `params` is an object or a method.

Comment: "`params` is a method. Every method returns an object in Ruby. In this case, `params` returns an instance of ..."