# Rails + Heroku + Multiplayer Game (poker)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, poker

I'm working on a project for fun.  I've never created a multi-player game before so I decided to build one.  For the sake of simplification; let's just say this game is online poker because the game mechanics are the same. Think: players sit at table; players take turns (timed) making moves; chat; etc.

My current setup is the following.  Rails3 website hosted on Heroku.  The website contains working logins (devise + heroku db) and a websocket chat room.

What I'm wondering is; seeing as all the Rails stuff is session based.  How do I handle the turn timer?  Don't I need some piece of the equation that holds the state across all the sessions and is able to keep track of time / throw events? Do I need a separate server? Or can I run this thing via my current setup?

If I do need another server; how do I do this with Rails?  Another Heroku app? Is this possible under Heroku?  Kinda new to Rails; so any help understanding this would be very much obliged.

Btw; any articles related to this topic would be much appreciated.

Can this be done with Delayed Jobs?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into EventMachine?

Comment: Is eventmachine often used for this type of solution?  I'm not familiar with EventMachine; but I will research it more today.

Comment: When I read your question, I thought about Node.js, but it seemed that you wanted something rails-related and EventMachine is said to have inspired Node.js If you're comfortable with javascript you may also want to checkout Node.js Many [games](http://nodeknockout.com/entries) have been built on the Node.js framework. Here's a [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540490/eventmachine-vs-node-js) comparing the two solutions.

Comment: Is there any reason why Delayed_Jobs wouldn't work here?  I figure all I need is a delayed job to that delays 20 seconds or so (whatever the player's turn time is).  When the delayed_job fires; it would check the database to see if the player ended up taking his turn; if he didn't it would resign his turn and start the next players turn. Does this sound like a decent solution; or am I missing something about delayed_jobs?