# Are inherited/mixed-in methods copies of the original?

Tags: ruby, methods

Given the various ways of sharing methods in Ruby, and the fact that those methods are themselves objects, what are the underlying mechanics of such sharing? For example, given:

```
module A
  def alpha; end
end

module B
  include A
end
```

is it accurate to say that B's `alpha` instance method is a *copy* of A's? It appears so:

```
alpha_a = A.instance_method(:alpha)
alpha_b = B.instance_method(:alpha)

alpha_a == alpha_b
=> false

alpha_a.object_id == alpha_b.object_id
=> false
```

This makes it look (to me) like alpha_b is a copy of alpha_a that belongs to B. But reading about Ruby's handling of method-lookup/dispatch, it sounds the call traverses the ancestors all the way back to A before finding the method to call. Also, there's this:

```
alpha_b.owner
=> A
```

So what exactly is going on? Do alpha_a and alpha_b both "reside" in A, despite the latter having been generated when B included A? Do the underlying mechanics depend on the mode of sharing (include/extend/inherit)?

Comment: You're generating the unbound method by calling `instance_method`. There's no "copy" of the module method itself; it resides in `A`.

Comment: Note that `B.ancestors #=> [B, A]`, `A.ancestors #=> [A]`. 
.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alpha_a` is an object that describes the method `alpha` on `A`. It is not the method itself. The method itself, just like a block, is *not an object*, just like blocks are not objects but can be wrapped in `Proc` objects. Similarly, `alpha_b` describes the method `alpha` on `B`.

The method itself is the same: it is defined on module `A`. There is no copying going on.

Comment: I thought methods were objects. For example, `m = Array.instance_method(:flatten) #=> #<UnboundMethod: Array#flatten> `. `m.is_a? Object #=> true`. Is my reasoning faulty?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: `Method`s and `UnboundMethod`s are objects that describe methods, which are not. The distinction between `Method` and method is important here.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602340/methods-in-ruby-objects-or-not

Comment: Thanks. One more for the to-do list.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I just thought of a good analogy that makes it clear. Are files objects in Ruby? Clearly no - files are not in Ruby, but on the disk. But `File`s are objects (in Ruby) that describe - and allow you to interact with - files (on the disk). A `File` is not a file (clearly); the very same reasoning applies to Ruby methods, even if it is not as obvious.,.

Comment: Yes, a great analogy.