# Why does calling 'is_a? Object' on a method return 'true'?

Tags: ruby, methods

A ruby method is an `Object`. For example:

```
def method
  'does something'
end
method.is_a? Object #=> true

def method; end 
method.is_a? Object #=> true
```

Why is a method a `Object`?

Comment: Everything is an object. You can’t get very far into Ruby-land without hearing that phrase. It’s true though, everything in Ruby is an object. The interesting thing is how those objects are linked together and classified.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Methods in Ruby: objects or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602340/methods-in-ruby-objects-or-not)

Comment: You are not inspecting methods in your samples, but  objects returned by them - in first case a `String`, in second - `nil`. Try `method.class` to check that, the `method` is called and `is_a?` is called on it's return value. Methods have class `Method`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Ilya Konyukhov wrote, calling `method.is_a?(Object)` checks the **return value** of calling `method`, which would be `"does something"` and `nil` respectively - both of which are `Object`s.

Rubys methods [are not objects per se](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602340/methods-in-ruby-objects-or-not) but you can get an **object representation** of them using the [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-method) method.

The funny part of your specific example is, that you unfortunately named your test method "method", thus overwriting your `self`s method `method`.

Take a look at this example, where I named my method "test" instead:

```
def test; end

test.class.name          => "NilClass"

method(:test).class.name => "Method"
```

As you see, `test` is **calling** the method and everything after (e.g. `is_a?` or `class.name`) is called on the **return value**.

`method(:test)`, however, returns an object representation (of class `Method`) of the method itself.

Comment: Your second paragraph is misleading. What is normally meant by "method" and an instance of `Method` class are different things. The OP meant the former, not the latter.

Comment: @sawa changed my answer so that it does not imply that methods are identical with instances of the class `Method`.

Answer (score 2):

`method.is_a?(Object)`

can be rewritten as

```
res = method
res.is_a?(Object)
```

So you call a method and ask if its result -- a `String` instance -- is an `Object`. For sure it is.

It can be easily verified with:

```
method.is_a?(String) # also returns true
```

*Update*:

If you want to check if a method itself an `Object` or not, you can do it with this code snippet:

```
def method2
  "some string"
end

method2_ref = Object.method(:method2) # #<Method: Object.method2>
method2_ref.is_a? Object # true
method2_ref.is_a? String # false
```

As it is mentioned in the comments, `Method` instance is also an `Object`.

Comment: What about this case

    def method; end
    method.is_a? Object

Comment: ```def method; end``` returns ```nil```, which is also an ```Object``` :)

Comment: @IlyaKonyukhov `def method; end` returns `:method` since Ruby 2.1

Comment: Correct. In my comment I meant _calling_ method defined as ```def method; end``` returns ```nil```.

Answer (score 1):

"Ruby' s methods are not objects in the way that strings, numbers and arrays are" (The Ruby Programming Language, Flanagan and Matsumoto, page 176).  OP' s method name "method" is unfortunate; it makes it almost impossible to explain anything. If you need to treat a method as an object, there is the [method method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-method), which results in an [instance of Class Method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Method.html).